# Check that ValidationError is actually the one I expect in a test

Tags: django, testing

I have a test which creates a Django object "forgetting" to set one field. It should fail, so I check:

```
p = Person.objects.create(name='test') 
self.assertRaises(ValidationError, p.full_clean)
```

The forgotten field is `birth_date`, so if I intercepted the exception and printed it, the error would be:

```
{'birth_date': ['This field cannot be blank.']}`
```

Now I added another field to `Person`, which also shouldn't be left blank. The error now would be:

```
{'birth_date': ['This field cannot be blank.'], 'category': ['This field cannot be blank.']}
```

With the above code, I silently suppress both errors. I need to test that the code raises a specific validation error. Is there a good way to do it? For now I've this workaround:

```
try:
    p.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    self.assertIn('birth_date', dict(e))
    self.assertEqual(len(dict(e).keys()), 1, msg="Expected one error, found more")
```

But if there could have been two different errors with 'birth_date', this would catch either.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by: *But if there could have been two different errors with 'birth_date', this would again catch both.* ? There would be only one key, and the list would have multiple values - Moreover, you dont seem to be doing any validations on the error message

Comment: @karthikr, that's exactly what I mean. Should I check the error message explicitly? So, in total, the presence of the key, the total number of keys (should be only one), the number of items in the list for that key (should be only one), and explicitly the error message? It's long and especially the last check feels strange to me: the message text is more likely to change than the field name, right? I thought there should be something like "assert that the error which is raised is exactly this one".